# How to extract interger from a string

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to find the sum of the two numbers. These are my codes for server and client, the result I want is

CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 46

but instead I get

CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 12

CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 34

Client:

```
    import socket

def parse_file(fName):
    list = []
    with open(fName) as f:
        for line in 1f:
            list.append(line.strip())
    return list


HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

   input_data = parse_file('foo')

for i in input_data:
    s.sendall(str(i))
    sum = s.recv(1024)
    print "CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum ", sum

s.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket

def compute_sum(line):
    result = sum(int(i) for i in line)
    return result

HOST = 'localhost'                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    print "SERVER RECIEVED : ", repr(data)
    compute_sum(data)

    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

foo

```
23
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is inside your loop, and sum is being set to the new value each time through, rather than incremented by the appropriate amount. Try this instead:

```
sum = 0

for i in input_data:
    s.sendall(str(i))
    sum += int(s.recv(1024))

print "CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum ", sum
```

Comment: getting this error...TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @user7576454 Wrap the call to `recv()` in a call to `int()`. I edited the answer to include that. Sorry, I didn't realize what `recv()` was returning. The reason you weren't getting that error in your original code is because you were printing it right away without trying to do math on it.

Comment: bingo, its working...!!! but how do I avoid multiple outputs : CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum  12
CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum  46
i need only the second output

Comment: @user7576454 Did you pull the print outside your for loop like I have it? Double check your indentation. If the print is outside the for loop you should only be getting the final output after all the values are summed up.

Comment: is there a way to avoid using 'foo' and user inputs the numbers?

Comment: @user7576454 Sure. You can use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get user input.